# Issue with eas build when changing app.json "name" changes

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I'm encountering an issue while using eas to build a React Native project created with Expo(not bare). When I modify the "name" field in app.json (changing it to "Çevrim dışı İngilizce" for example), which includes non-ASCII Turkish characters, eas build fails. However, if I keep the name unchanged, there are no errors. I'll share the Gradle logs for reference. Due to restrictions during project creation, I'm unable to have Turkish characters in the name field initially, thus the necessity to change it afterwards. Any insights on resolving this would be greatly appreciated.
My Gradle logs are:

```
Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
10%
20%.
30%.
40%
50
%.
60%.
70%
80%
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.3!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Faster Java compilation
- Reduced memory usage
 - Support for running on Java 20
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
> Configure project :
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
> Configure project :expo-modules-core
Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 accepted.
Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393".
"Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393" ready.
Installing NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.1.8937393
"Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393" complete.
"Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393" finished.
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
> Configure project :expo
Using expo modules
  - [32mexpo-constants[0m (15.4.5)
  - [32mexpo-file-system[0m (16.0.8)
  - [32mexpo-font[0m (11.10.3)
  - [32mexpo-keep-awake[0m (12.8.2)
  - [32mexpo-modules-core[0m (1.11.10)
  - [32mexpo-modules-core$android-annotation[0m (1.11.10)
  - [32mexpo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor[0m (1.11.10)
  - [32mexpo-speech[0m (11.7.0)
  - [32mexpo-sqlite[0m (13.3.0)
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 34 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 34 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 34 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/34.0.0
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 34 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 34 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 3)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 34 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-34
"Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 3)" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 v.33.0.1".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 v.33.0.1" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/33.0.1
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 v.33.0.1" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.1 v.33.0.1" finished.
> Task :expo-modules-core$android-annotation-processor:processResources
> Task :expo-constants:createExpoConfig
> Task :expo-constants:preBuild
> Task :expo-constants:preReleaseBuild
...
> Task :expo-sqlite:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :expo-sqlite:mergeReleaseJavaResource
> Task :expo-sqlite:syncReleaseLibJars
> Task :expo-sqlite:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :expo-sqlite:writeReleaseLintModelMetadata
> Task :expo-sqlite:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :expo-sqlite:bundleLibRuntimeToJarRelease
> Task :expo-sqlite:createFullJarRelease
> Task :expo-sqlite:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :expo-sqlite:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :expo-sqlite:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
> Task :expo-sqlite:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar
> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    provider#expo.modules.filesystem.FileSystemFileProvider@android:authorities was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:0 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
> Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :app:processReleaseResources
> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :app:extractReleaseNativeSymbolTables
> Task :app:compileReleaseKotlin
FAILED
e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/java/com/aceylan/ingilizce_cevrimdisi/MainActivity.kt:18:14 Unresolved reference: R
e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/java/com/aceylan/ingilizce_cevrimdisi/MainActivity.kt:35:11 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/java/com/aceylan/ingilizce_cevrimdisi/MainApplication.kt:35:60 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/java/com/aceylan/ingilizce_cevrimdisi/MainApplication.kt:37:52 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/java/com/aceylan/ingilizce_cevrimdisi/MainApplication.kt:38:51 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/java/com/aceylan/ingilizce_cevrimdisi/MainApplication.kt:48:10 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/java/com/aceylan/ingilizce_cevrimdisi/MainApplication.kt:51:9 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/java/com/aceylan/ingilizce_cevrimdisi/MainApplication.kt:55:9 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
> Task :app:mergeReleaseNativeDebugMetadata
> Task :app:optimizeReleaseResources
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 8m 19s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
414 actionable tasks: 414 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

My package.json content is

```
{
  "name": "Çevrim dışı İngilizce",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.18",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.26",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.15",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.27",
    "expo": "~50.0.11",
    "expo-asset": "^9.0.2",
    "expo-file-system": "^16.0.8",
    "expo-speech": "^11.7.0",
    "expo-sqlite": "^13.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.15.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.12.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.29.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [GH Issue](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/4289), this is a known limitation for the `name` field.  The recommendation in that thread is to use Localization to change your app's name.

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution. It is about "İ" character. I can use "çşöğü" etc, but if I use "İ", it fails. I have used "i" instead of "İ".

Comment: I have run into issues with the Turkish "undotted ı" and "dotted İ" for a few decades now  :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. It is about "İ" character. I can use "çşöğü" etc, but if I use "İ", it fails. I have used "i" instead of "İ"

Comment: feel free to accept your own answer.  It will help others to find this question and answer in the future.